# Recuperar valores passados por Jquey em uma página ASP

Tags: jquery, variáveis, asp

Caros amigos,

estou com um grande problema, criei uma página que carrega mais valores (load more) onde informo valores via Jquery e recupero em outra pagina ASP através de request exemplo:

```
page_number = Request("page")
```

Veja o código Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#load_more_button").hide();
$("#load_more_button").delay(2000).fadeIn('fast');

var track_click = 0; //track user click on "load more" button, righ now it is 0 click

var register_per_page = 8;

var total_pages = 3,625;

$('#results').load("links_mais.asp", {'page':track_click, 'reg_per_page':register_per_page}, function() {track_click++;}); //initial data to load

$(".load_more").click(function (e) { //user clicks on button

    $(this).hide(); //hide load more button on click
    $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

    if(track_click <= total_pages) //user click number is still less than total pages
    {
        //post page number and load returned data into result element
        $.post('links_mais.asp',{'page': track_click, 'reg_per_page':register_per_page}, function(data) {

            $(".load_more").show(); //bring back load more button

            $("#results").append(data); //append data received from server

            //scroll page smoothly to button id
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#ate_aqui").offset().top}, 500);

            //hide loading image
            $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

            track_click++; //user click increment on load button

        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?
            alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
            $(".load_more").show(); //bring back load more button
            $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received
        });


        if(track_click >= total_pages-1) //compare user click with page number
        {
            //reached end of the page yet? disable load button
            $(".load_more").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
     }

    });
});
```

Observe as linhas:

```
var register_per_page = 8;

var total_pages = 3,625;
```

Estes valores são passados para o arquivo: links_mais.asp.

No meu server offline roda normal, mas online não.

Porque isso acontece? Alguém sabe dizer?

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: No teu servidor online, tu já tentou acessar a página `links_mais.asp` no servidor passando os mesmos parâmetros que a requisição jQuery passa? O que acontece?

Comment: Por questão de segurança talves o servidor não deixe usar apenas Request(). Tente usar o `Request.Form` de seus dados forem enviados via POST, ou o `Request.QueryString` se seus dador forem enviados via GET